# Finding optimal index for this MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

In MySQL slow query log I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `news_items`
WHERE `ctime` > 1465013901 AND `feed_id` IN (1, 2, 9) AND
`moderated` = '1' AND `visibility` = '1'
ORDER BY `views` DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Here is the result of EXPLAIN:

```
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys                                                                         | key   | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | news_items | index | feed_id,ctime,ctime_2,feed_id_2,moderated,visibility,feed_id_3,cday_complex,feed_id_4 | views | 4       | NULL |    5 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I run this query manually, it takes like 0.00 sec but for some reason it appears in MySQL's slow log taking 1-5 seconds sometimes. I believe it happens when server is under high load.

Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `news_items` (
  `item_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `source_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `feed_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `announce` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `content` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `hyperlink` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `ctime` varchar(11) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `cday` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `img` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `video` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `gallery` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `comments` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `views` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `visibility` enum('1','0') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pin` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `pin_dttm` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `moderated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The index named as "views" consists of 1 field only -- views.
I also have many other indexes consisting of (for example):

```
feed_id + views + visibility + moderated
moderated + visibility + feed_id + ctime
moderated + visibility + feed_id + views + ctime
```

I used fields in mentioned order because that was the only reason MySQL started to use them. However, I never got "Using where; using index" in EXPLAIN.

Any ideas on how to make EXPLAIN to show me "using index"?

Comment: basic rule of thumb: any field used in a decision context (e.g. used in a `where`, `join`, `order by`, etc...) should be indexed. your indexes seem redundant. if a field shows up in multiple indexes, it'd probably be better off being its own separate index. e.g. if moderated gets changed, you force changing three separate indexes, rather than just one.

Comment: I will delete most of these indexes when I find the best one. It's just an example of what I do to find a good index. Anyway, thank you for your comment, I will bear it in mind.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer your question: "using index" means that MySQL will use *only* index to satisfy your query. To do this we will need to create a "covered" index (index which "covers" the query) = index which covers both "where" and "order by/group by" and all fields from "select"  However, you are doing "select *" so that will not be practical.

MySQL chooses index on views as you have limit 5 in the query. It does that as 1) index is small 2) it can avoid filesort in this case.

I believe the problem is not with the index but rather than with the engine=MyISAM. MyISAM uses table level lock, so if you change the news_items it will be locked. I would suggest converting table to InnoDB.

Another possibility may be that if the table is large, index on (views) may not be the best option.

If you use Percona Server you can enable slow log verbosity option and see the query plan for the slow query as described here: https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/diagnostics/slow_extended_55.html

Comment: Hi Alexander! Thanks for your answer. So you believe that "views" is the best index ATM for this MyISAM table? It has 30k rows, 80Mbytes. I'll try to make some tests on InnoDB. BTW, I make full-text search on this table using Sphinx so migration won't be a big problem I assume.

Comment: Greg, also starting with MySQL 5.6 you can use InnoDB with fulltext indexes. Using Sphinx is a good approach as well. With 80Mb table I would say the index on views may be the easiest and the best here. I would also suggest cleaning up other indexes as some of them look like duplicated. In MySQL 5.6+ you can also use performance schema to find all unused indexes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have change the storage engine to InnoDB and create the correct composite index you can try this. The first query only gets the item_id for the first 5 rows. Limit is done after the complete SELECT is done. So its better to do this without any big data and then get the hole row only from the 5 woes

```
SELECT idata.* FROM (
  SELECT item_id FROM `news_items`
  WHERE `ctime` > 1465013901 AND `feed_id` IN (1, 2, 9) AND
  `moderated` = '1' AND `visibility` = '1'
  ORDER BY `views` DESC
  LIMIT 5 ) as i_ids
LEFT JOIN news_items AS idata ON idata.item_id = i_ids.item_id
ORDER BY `views` DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table "also have many other indexes", why do they not show in the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`?

There are two ways that

```
WHERE `ctime` > 1465013901
  AND `feed_id` IN (1, 2, 9)
  AND `moderated` = '1'
  AND `visibility` = '1'
ORDER BY `views` DESC
```

could use indexing:

- `INDEX(views)` and hope that the desired 5 rows (see `LIMIT`) show up early.
- `INDEX(moderated, visibility, feed_id, ctime)`

This last 'composite' index starts with the two columns (in either order) that are compared `= constant`, then moves on to `IN` and finally a "range" (`ctime > const`).  Older versions won't get past `IN`; newer versions will leapfrog through the `IN` values and make use of the range on `ctime`.  [More discussion](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

It is useless to include the `ORDER BY` columns in a composite index before *all* of the `WHERE` columns.  However, it will not be useful to include `views` in your case because the "range" on `ctime`.

The tip about 'lazy evaluation' that Bernd suggests will also help.

I agree that InnoDB would probably be better.  [Conversion tips](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb).